# Can I extract controller functions to external files?

Tags: angularjs

My controller is getting somewhat busy and finding the function that I'm looking for is becoming cumbersome. I'd like to have individual files for some of my controller functions. How can I achieve this? Is there something like `ng-include` for the controller to use?

Comment: See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Comment: @Aliz I don't really see how this is related to angular services

Comment: "I'd like to have individual files for some of my controller functions" made me think about "services", if it's not could you be more specific or give us examples ?

Comment: Ui router might be helpful https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: @Aliz the last sentence explains what OP's looking for

Comment: Oh sorry, i misunderstood the question

Comment: ui-router is about routing. I don't see how that's related to this question? @Aliz was right in my opinion. If your controller is too big, it's probably time to use a service.

Comment: @MattLishman Loading a controller dynamically is also about routing, and that is what it's about I think

Answer (score 0):

You might use the mixin pattern. This allows you to extend your controllers with other controllers. As a result you have now two different controllers, while both get executed at the same time:

```
app.controller('AnyController', ['$scope'
    function ($scope) {
      return {
          myFunction: function() {
               // do something
          }
      }
    }
]);

app.controller('MyMainController', ['$scope'
    function ($scope) {
      var anyThing = $controller('AnyController as anyThing',{$scope: $scope}),
      $scope.anyThing = function() {
          // those two options are now both valid:
          anyThing.myFunction();   

          $scope.anyThing.myFunction();
      }
    }
]);
```

Now you are able to move your seperate controllers into different files.